# How to vertically center content in Twitter Bootstrap that works?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I have read previous questions and attempted their solutions, but none seem to work.

My example Bootstrap HTML is very simple:

```
...
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4" class="centering">
        span4
      </div>
      <div class="span8" class="centering">
        span8               
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
...
```

The CSS that describes the `centering` class is as follows:

```
.centering {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

The browsers render this code by putting the text `span4` and `span8` at the top of the browser window, instead of in the vertical middle of the browser window. What have I overlooked in setting this up?

Comment: only an observation but cant div class="span4" class="centering" become div class="span4 centering" ? do you want the content within the spans to be centered? if so try text align:center, not sure if im understanding the question? an example would help..see http://jsfiddle.net/BzYxM/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be very practical for you in a real-world scenario, but worth a look, anyhow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;padding:0}

.container-fluid{
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}

.row-fluid {height: 100%; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}

.centering {
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4" class="centering">
        span4
      </div>
      <div class="span8" class="centering">
        span8               
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not seem to work when there was content in both the `span4` and `span8` elements. It did seem to work when there was content in either `span4` or `span8`.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Seems to work for me if I add content to both of those divs ... unless I'm missing something. Are you talking about a lot of content?

Comment: Just text in one div (a sentence or two) and an image in the other.